# mobile redirect project runs locally, and fails in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect, mobile

I have a small mobile redirect project that runs perfectly on my local machine, but in production, it breaks on the search click.

Here is some more info:
- The redirect sub-routine in in Page_Load in site.master.cs
- I used if/else statements to run through all the mobile URL params
- Works perfectly on my local machine
- I have not incorporated any session variables(removed them), that was breaking it earlier.

Here is the code:

```
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true){
                HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;//GET current http request header           
                string mRoot = "m.website.com";//Mobile root URL
                string path = httpRequest.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().ToLower();//GET original destination path
                string protocol = "http://";//protocol used
                string RedirectTo = protocol + mRoot;//Mobile Destination URL
                string webRoot = protocol + "www.website.com/autos.aspx";// Root URL
                string userAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
                string QueryString = Request.QueryString.ToString().ToLower();
                string listingID = Request.PathInfo.ToString();
                string make = string.Empty;
                string model = string.Empty;
                string zip = GetUserZip();//Get Zipcode
                string distance = Request.Cookies["Search"]["distance"];
                string redirectedUrl = string.Empty;//Destination URL
                string status = string.Empty;
                string location = string.Empty;
                CommonService _common = new CommonService();
                Uri uri = new Uri(_common.GetSiteBaseURL());
                NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
                // www.website.com/autos/results/all/all/refine?pagenum=1&perpage=30&sort=price desc&zipcode=33716&inv=false
                // 
                // "Default" 
                // If “/results/” is NOT contained in the URL and “/listing/” is NOT contained in the URL
                if ((!path.Contains("/results/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && (!path.Contains("/listing/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    if ((!path.Contains(make)) && (!path.Contains(model)))
                    {
                        // Send to Default page on Mobile
                        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                        Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://m.website.com/autos.aspx");

                        Response.Redirect(RedirectTo + "/autos.aspx");
                    }
                }
                // "VDP" 
                // If “/results/” is NOT contained in the URL and “/listing/” IS contained in the URL Send to the VDP page on Mobile
                if ((!path.Contains("/results/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && (path.Contains("/listing/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    if (path.Contains("/autos/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        string x = path.ToString(); // GET itemid here
                        string y = x.Split('/')[8];
                        string itemid = y;
                        // Capture everything after /listing/
                        if (itemid != null)//Add more verification to itemid
                        {
                            // Send to VDP mobile page
                            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://m.website.com/listingdetail.aspx");
                            Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listingdetail.aspx" + "?listID=" + itemid);
                        }

                    }
                    string p = path.ToString(); // GET itemid here
                    string j = p.Split('/')[5];
                    string _itemid = j;
                    // Send to VDP mobile page
                    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                    Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://m.website.com/listingdetail.aspx");
                    Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listingdetail.aspx" + "?listID=" + _itemid);                      
                }

                // "Search Results" 
                // If “/results/” IS contained in the URL, Send to the SearchResults page on Mobi
                if (path.Contains("/results/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    if (path.Contains("/autos/"))
                    {
                        string g = path.ToString();
                        make = g.Split('/')[5];
                        string m = make.ToString();
                        model = g.Split('/')[6];
                        string mm = model.ToString();
                        // If there are no more characters in the URL after MAKE  
                        if ((path.Contains(m, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && (path.Contains("&zipcode=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))// && (path.Contains("&model=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                        {
                            if (mm.Contains("--", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                // Trim one of the -'s from model if it has two '--'
                                mm = (mm.Trim().Replace("--", "-"));
                            }
                            // END if (path.Contains("--", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice&make=" + m + "&model=" + mm + "&zip=" + zip + "&miles=" + distance);
                        } 
                        if (path.Contains("&zipcode=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + "&make=" + m + "&zip=" + zip + "&miles=" + distance);
                        }
                         // Set URL to URL + MAKE
                        if (mm.Contains("all"))
                        {
                            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + "&make=" + m + "&zip=" + zip + "&miles=" + distance);
                        }
                        // Otherwise set URL to URL + Make + Model
                        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                        Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + "&make=" + m + "&model=" + mm);
                        if (path.Contains("&zipcode=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + "&make=" + m + "&zip=" + zip);
                        }// END if (path.Contains("&zip=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                         // Send to search results on Mobi
                         // Set _make = text immediately following '/results/' and ending at next '/'
                         //  make = all

                        if (path.Contains("/all/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            // Set _model = text immediately following '/results/_make/' and ending at next '/'
                            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + mm + "/all/" + distance);
                        } // END if (path.Contains("/all/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                          // If MODEL = “all/” then
                        if (path.Contains("/all/all/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            //
                            Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                            Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + "/all/all/" + distance);
                        } // END if (path.Contains("/all/all/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                          //  If MODEL contains “--" then make sure in redirect that it only gets 1 '-'
                        if (mm.Contains("--", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {

                            mm = (mm.Trim().Replace("&#8209;", "-"));

                            // Set ZIP = Text immediately following “&zipcode =” and ending at next “&”
                            if (path.Contains("&zipcode=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                                Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + "?make=" + m + "&model=" + mm + "&zip=" + zip);
                            } // END if (path.Contains("&zip=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            if (!path.Contains("&miles", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                distance = "1500";
                                // Set URL to URL +  “&miles=1500” - This is the value used for unlimited distance
                                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                                Response.RedirectPermanent(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice" + "&make=" + m + "&miles=" + distance);
                            } // END if (!path.Contains("&miles", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        } // END if (path.Contains("/results/"))
                          // All other links will go here...          
                          // Call the Redirect() method 
                          // Redirects to new URL specifying URL

                        Response.RedirectPermanent(protocol + mRoot + "/autos.apsx");

                    }

                    string r = Request.FilePath.ToString();
                    string Make = r.Split('/')[2];
                    string _m = Make.ToString();
                    string Model = r.Split('/')[3];
                    string _mm = model.ToString();
                    // If there are no more characters in the URL after MAKE  
                    if ((path.Contains(_m, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && (path.Contains("&zipcode=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))// && (path.Contains("&model=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                    {
                        if (_mm.Contains("--", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            // Trim one of the -'s from model if it has two '--'
                            _mm = (_mm.Trim().Replace("--", "-"));
                        }
                        // END if (path.Contains("--", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))


                        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                        Response.Redirect(protocol + mRoot + "/listings.aspx?sort=HighestPrice&make=" + _m + "&model=" + _mm + "&zip=" + zip + "&miles=" + distance);


                    }
                }
            }


}
```

Please let me know if I have not given enough information. I have been working on this for a couple days and need to get it working. I also need to know if the master page is the best place for this or should I create a new .cs file and call the method from each page that needs redirected to mobile.

Comment: Is there any error message? What do you mean by "break"?

Comment: you need to show the line it breaks on (debug output)

Comment: I can't, it is not breaking locally and when live it goes to our error page. I cannot change this in production(custom error mode)

Comment: When I click search from home page, it goes directly to error page in prod env., locally it does not.

Comment: Check Event Viewer and see what the error is.

Comment: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: at Company.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Builds\1\WebSite\Autos\Sources\CompanyInformation Systems\WebSite\Autos\autos\Site.master.cs:line 136

Comment: line 136: string location= string.Empty;

Comment: Found the solution. Thanks all for the comments. I removed the erroneous line of code(string location = string.Empty). I used another way of obtaining the location when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Thanks all for the comments. I removed the erroneous line of code(string location = string.Empty). I discovered I did not need to obtain the location in this code block for the redirect to properly work.